# calculate $\cos(\alpha+\beta)$ and $\sin(\alpha+\beta)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, rotations

The following transformation matrix describes a rotation $r_α :\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}^2$ that rotates with angle $α$ to the left around the null vector with respect to the standard basis  :

$M^B_B(r_α)$=$\left( \begin{array}{rrr}
\cos(α) & -\sin(α)  \\ 
\sin(α) & \cos(α)  \\ 
\end{array}\right)$.

If i first rotate with angle $α$ and then with angle $\beta$ it would be the same as $\alpha+\beta$.

How could i apply the given information to derive formulas to calculate $\cos(\alpha+\beta)$ and $\sin(\alpha+\beta)$ using $\cos(\alpha)$, $\sin(\alpha)$, $\cos(\beta)$, $\sin(\beta)$ ?

Thanks for any type of help :)

Comment: Composition of functions corresponds to multiplication of matrices. So multiply the matrix corresponding by $\alpha$ by the one corresponding by $\beta$. On the one hand, this should be the matrix corresponding to $\alpha+\beta$, but on the other you will get expressions in terms of the sines and cosines of $\alpha$ and of $\beta$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\begin{bmatrix}
\cos \alpha  & -\sin \alpha \\
\sin \alpha  & \cos \alpha 
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
\cos \beta  & -\sin \beta \\
\sin \beta  & \cos \beta 
\end{bmatrix} =\begin{bmatrix}
\cos( \alpha +\beta ) & -\sin( \alpha +\beta )\\
\sin( \alpha +\beta ) & \cos( \alpha +\beta )
\end{bmatrix}$$

Multiply.

**Expanding on my answer.**

We want rotation matrices to behave in a natural way. I.e if
$$\mathbf{R}(\theta)=\begin{bmatrix}
\cos \theta  & -\sin \theta \\
\sin \theta  & \cos \theta 
\end{bmatrix}$$
Intuitively, a rotation of an angle $\alpha+\beta$ should be the same as a composition of a rotation by an angle $\alpha$ and then an angle $\beta$. Since composition of matrices corresponds to multiplication of them, this means we would expect
$$\mathbf{R}(\alpha)\mathbf{R}(\beta)=\mathbf{R}(\alpha+\beta) \\ \begin{bmatrix}
\cos \alpha  & -\sin \alpha \\
\sin \alpha  & \cos \alpha 
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
\cos \beta  & -\sin \beta \\
\sin \beta  & \cos \beta 
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
\cos (\alpha+\beta)  & -\sin (\alpha+\beta) \\
\sin (\alpha+\beta)  & \cos (\alpha+\beta)
\end{bmatrix}$$
If you multiply the two matrices on the left, this gives you
$$\begin{bmatrix}
\cos\alpha\cos\beta-\sin\alpha\sin\beta  & -\sin\alpha\cos\beta-\cos\alpha\sin\beta \\
\sin\alpha\cos\beta+\cos\alpha\sin\beta  & \cos\alpha\cos\beta-\sin\alpha\sin\beta 
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
\cos (\alpha+\beta)  & -\sin (\alpha+\beta) \\
\sin (\alpha+\beta)  & \cos (\alpha+\beta)
\end{bmatrix}$$
I.e, matching the components of the two equivalent matrices,
$$\cos (\alpha+\beta)=\cos\alpha\cos\beta-\sin\alpha\sin\beta \\ \sin (\alpha+\beta)=\sin\alpha\cos\beta+\cos\alpha\sin\beta$$
Alternatively, reversing the sign of $\beta$ we get
$$\cos (\alpha-\beta)=\cos\alpha\cos\beta+\sin\alpha\sin\beta \\ \sin (\alpha-\beta)=\sin\alpha\cos\beta-\cos\alpha\sin\beta$$
*Exercise*: Try combining the expressions for $\cos(\alpha-\beta),\cos(\alpha+\beta)$ to get an expression for $\cos(\alpha)\cos(\beta)$ and similarly for $\sin$.

Comment: How would i go on from here/how could i simplify/are there theorems i could use?
$\left[ \begin{array}{rrr}
cos(α)*cos(β)+(-sin(α))*sin(β) & cos(α)*(-sin(β))+(-sin(α))*cos(β)  \\ 
 sin(α)*cos(β)+cos(α)*sin(β) &sin(α)*(-sin(β))+cos(α)*cos(β) \\
\end{array}\right]$

Comment: @Mathaddict234 At this point you are done! Those are the addition formulae for sine and cosine.

Comment: But i have to calculate each step?$cos(α)*cos(β)=1/2 cos(α+β) +1/ 2cos(α-β)$ and so on.., or is there a theorem i could use?

Comment: @Mathaddict234 See my expanded answer.

Comment: I don't understand how we get for example $cos(α+β)$ from $cos(α)∗cos(β)+(−sin(α))∗sin(β)$? How is this simplified?Is there a lemma or rule to do this?

Comment: @Mathaddict234 That's the formula we're trying to derive. We start from the **postulate** that rotation matrices should behave nicely, i.e $\mathbf{R}(\alpha)\mathbf{R}(\beta)=\mathbf{R}(\alpha+\beta)$. After expanding out the matrix on the left and matching the components, we see that our postulate is true **if and only if** all of the components are equal, i.e, the addition formulae for sine and cosine. 
If you are willing to take the postulate without proof, the addition formulas for sine and cosine are a direct result.

Comment: How would the proof look like? Is there a link to a website or could you explain it?

Comment: It's simply the intuitive notion that rotating by $\alpha$ and then by $\beta$ is the same as rotating by $\alpha+\beta$.