# Why is $\cos(\alpha+\beta) = \cos(\alpha)\cos(\beta)−\sin(\alpha)\sin(\beta)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, rotations, transformation

I already posted [a question about transformation matrices and rotation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4331961/calculate-cos-alpha-beta-and-sin-alpha-beta). But I'm not satisfied with the answer.

They simply said

> Composition of functions corresponds to multiplication of matrices.

I think I understand the concept but I'm still confused why exactly $$\cos(\alpha + \beta)=\cos(\alpha)\cos(\beta)−\sin(\alpha)\sin(\beta)$$

Is there a lemma or formula I have to use or does it simply derive from distributivity of matrix multiplication? I can't get my head around it.

Comment: How are you defining $\cos$? The proof varies greatly depending on the definition.

Comment: The following transformation matrix describes a rotation $r_α :\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}^2$ that rotates with angle $α$ to the left around the null vector with respect to the standard basis  : 

$M^B_B(r_α)$=$\left( \begin{array}{rrr}
\cos(α) & -\sin(α)  \\ 
\sin(α) & \cos(α)  \\ 
\end{array}\right)$.

If i first rotate with angle $α$ and then with angle $\beta$ it would be the same as $\alpha+\beta$.

Comment: That's not a definition

Comment: i don't understand what you mean

Comment: I asked, how are you defining $\cos$. If I didn't know what $\cos(x)$ was, how would you define it for me?

Comment: cosine is the ratio of the length of the adjacent leg to that of the hypotenuse

Comment: [Youtube Proof](https://www.google.com/search?q=cos+sum+formula+right+triangle+proof&rlz=1C5CHFA_enUS907US907&sxsrf=AOaemvLOAomtSIGulgjZ3POWAE6qIOVfjw%3A1639600029791&ei=nU-6YdO5L7GIggejppbAAw&ved=0ahUKEwiT_OSK0ub0AhUxhOAKHSOTBTgQ4dUDCA4&uact=5&oq=cos+sum+formula+right+triangle+proof&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyBQghEKABOgQIABBHOgYIABAWEB46CAghEBYQHRAeOgUIIRCrAkoECEEYAEoECEYYAFCGBVj6ImDMI2gCcAN4AIABigGIAc0RkgEFMTIuMTCYAQCgAQHIAQjAAQE&sclient=gws-wiz#kpvalbx=_pE-6YaHWEsGQggev0qnQBA17) [HTML proof](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/triangle/SinCosFormula.shtml)

Comment: Is there a proof in context with linear transformation and  distributivity of matrix multiplication?

Comment: Yes, the one in the answer to the question you linked. Rotating by angle $\alpha$, then by angle $\beta$, is the same as rotating by angle $\alpha+\beta$. So $$R(\alpha+\beta)=R(\alpha)\circ R(\beta)$$ Comparing the elements of the left and right sides of this equation will get you the result.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. The rotation of $\mathbb R^2$ through angle $\alpha$ is a linear transformation with matrix
   $\left( \begin{matrix}
    \cos\alpha & -\sin\alpha\\ 
      \sin\alpha &\cos\alpha
   \end{matrix}\right)$
2. The rotation of $\mathbb R^2$ through angle $\beta$ is a linear transformation with matrix
   $\left( \begin{matrix}
    \cos\beta & -\sin\beta\\ 
      \sin\beta &\cos\beta
   \end{matrix}\right)$
3. The rotation of $\mathbb R^2$ through angle $\alpha+\beta$ is a linear transformation with matrix
   $\left( \begin{matrix}
    \cos(\alpha+\beta) & -\sin(\alpha+\beta)\\ 
      \sin(\alpha+\beta) &\cos(\alpha+\beta)
   \end{matrix}\right)$
4. The rotation of $\mathbb R^2$ through angle $\alpha+\beta$ is the composition of the rotation of $\mathbb R^2$ through angle $\alpha$ and the rotation of $\mathbb R^2$ through angle $\beta$.
5. The matrix of the composition of two linear transformations is the product of matrices of these transformations.
6. So $$ \left( \begin{matrix}
    \cos\alpha & -\sin\alpha\\ 
      \sin\alpha &\cos\alpha
   \end{matrix}\right)\cdot \left( \begin{matrix}
    \cos\beta & -\sin\beta\\ 
      \sin\beta &\cos\beta
   \end{matrix}\right) = \left( \begin{matrix}
    \cos(\alpha+\beta) & -\sin(\alpha+\beta)\\ 
      \sin(\alpha+\beta) &\cos(\alpha+\beta)
   \end{matrix}\right)$$
7. So, in particular, $$\cos(\alpha+\beta)=\cos\alpha\cos\beta-\sin\alpha\sin\beta.$$

Comment: And as for why rotation by a constant angle is a linear transformation, I like to give the geometric argument that the rotation takes a parallelogram to a parallelogram and therefore preserves sums; and similarly, the rotation takes parallel resp. antiparallel vectors to parallel resp. antiparallel vectors with the same scale factor and therefore preserves scalar multiples.

Comment: @DanielSchepler: Yes, just draw a picture. If you rotate a parallelogram, the result is a parallelogram. It is obvious, but I never tried to deduce it from Euclidean axioms.

Answer (score 10):

You can also simply prove it using complex  numbers :
$$ e^{i(\alpha + \beta)} = e^{i\alpha} \times e^{i\beta} 
 \Leftrightarrow \cos (a+b)+i \sin (a+b)=(\cos a+i \sin a) \times(\cos b+i \sin b) $$
Finally we obtain, after distributing :

$$ \cos (a+b)+i \sin (a+b) =\cos a \cos b-\sin a \sin b+i(\sin a \cos b+\cos a \sin b) $$

By identifying the real and imaginary parts we get

$$
\cos (a+b)=\cos a \cos b-\sin a \sin b
$$
$$ \sin (a+b)=\sin a \cos b+\cos a \sin b $$

Of course you need know basics about complex numbers but if you already know all of this it is usually really quick to proove most of this cumbersome trigonometric formulas with complex numbers like what I did here.

Comment: (+1) This is the same as the matrix approach when we identify $x+iy\leftrightarrow\begin{bmatrix}x&-y\\y&x\end{bmatrix}$

Answer (score 1):

A matrix represents a linear transformation. Each of its columns contains the coordinates of the transformed base. To apply it to a vector, multiply each column of the matrix by the corresponding coordinate (x coordinate for first column, etc.) and add the results. Applying a matrix to a matrix is applying the left-hand matrix to each column (base vector) of the right-hand matrix. This boils down to the "multiply row by column" rule.

To see that matrix columns form a transformed base in the case of a rotation, consider that the first column contains the coordinates $\cos \alpha$ and $\sin \alpha$ of the $\mathbf i$ vector rotated by $\alpha$. The second column is the first column rotated by $\pi / 2$. For example, for a $\pi / 4$ rotation, your first column will be $(1/\sqrt 2, 1/\sqrt 2)^T$.

Linear algebra done wrong, by Sergei Treil, lays out these principles from the start.

Answer (score 1):

You can also prove it by using a simple lemma:

Let $f:{\mathbb R}\to {\mathbb R}$ be twice differentiable, such that $f''=-f$. Then $f(x) = f(0)\cos x + f'(0) \sin x$.

Indeed, if $g(x)= f(x) - f(0)\cos x - f'(0)\sin x$, then $g''=-g$ and $g(0)=g'(0)=0$. But $(g'^2+g^2)' = 2 g'(g''+g) = 0$, hence $g'^2+g^2$ is a constant, which is $0$ because of its value at $x=0$. Hence $g(x)=0$ everywhere.

Applying this to $f(x) = \cos(x+\beta)$, we have $f(0) = \cos\beta$ and $f'(0) = -\sin\beta$, hence
\begin{equation}
\cos(x+\beta) = f(x) = \cos x\cos\beta - \sin x\sin\beta
\end{equation}

In the case of $h(x) = \sin(x+\beta)$, we have $h(0) = \sin\beta$ and $h'(0) = \cos\beta$, hence
\begin{equation}
\sin(x+\beta) = h(x) = \cos x\sin\beta + \sin x\cos\beta
\end{equation}

Answer (score 1):

By rotating the unit circle by an angle of $b$ we can see that the point $(cos(a-b),sin(a-b))$ maps to $(cos(a),sin(a))$ and the point $(1,0)$ maps to $(cos(b),sin(b))$.

Since rotations preserve distances,the distance between the points $(cos(a-b),sin(a-b))$ and $(1,0)$ is equal to the distance between points $(cos(a),sin(a))$ and $(cos(b),sin(b))$. The distance formula then gives:

$\sqrt{(cos(a-b)-1)^2+(sin(a-b)-0)^2}=\sqrt{(cos(a)-cos(b))^2+(sin(a)-sin(b))^2}$

With a lot less effort than you'd think (and using $sin(x)^2+cos(x)^2=1$ three times), you arrive at the desired identity